# Linux testdisk fails to repair MFT and rebuild BS, files lost?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, data-recovery

I have a Toshiba 1TB hard drive (HDWD110) that had a previous installation of Windows 10. Long story short, I ended up removing the entire disk partition using the Disc Manager on Linux.

Using the testdisk, I was able to 'rebuild' four partitions (the original disk was not partitioned, except by Windows boot reserved sector).

[image]

But I can't mount any of the important ones. If I try to rebuild the boot sectors, testdisk says "Sectors are identical".

[image]

When trying to repair the MFT, it says "MFT and MFT mirror are bad. Failed to repair them". Files can't be listed, with message "Can't open filesystem. Filesystem seems damaged".

Should I consider this disc files gone or is there anything else I can do?

Comment: Try something like Recuva  (https://www.ccleaner.com/recuva) and see if that recovers your files. If not, then they are gone.

Comment: “Should I consider this disc files gone or is there anything else I can do” - Data recovery services have additional tools that go well beyond Test Disk.  However, the time to have implemented those services and tools, were before you attempted to restore the partitions yourself more than likely